# How to detect shape in a video?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written this shape detection code that detects different shapes in a video, the code works well when the object that is being detected is standstill but doesn't detect shapes whilst the object is moving as the contours cannot be found from the canny whilst the object is moving. I have tried everything to solve this issue but I'm yet to find a solution. Can someone please help me figure out how to solve this issue, thank you in advance. The code is below.

```
/**
* Simple shape detector program.
* It loads an image and tries to find simple shapes (rectangle, triangle, circle, etc) in it.
* This program is a modified version of `squares.cpp` found in the OpenCV sample dir.
*/
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/**
* Helper function to find a cosine of angle between vectors
* from pt0->pt1 and pt0->pt2
*/
static double angle(cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2, cv::Point pt0)
{
double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

/**
* Helper function to display text in the center of a contour
*/
void setLabel(cv::Mat& im, const std::string label, std::vector<cv::Point>& contour)
{
int fontface = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
double scale = 0.4;
int thickness = 1;
int baseline = 0;

cv::Size text = cv::getTextSize(label, fontface, scale, thickness, &baseline);
cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contour);

cv::Point pt(r.x + ((r.width - text.width) / 2), r.y + ((r.height + text.height) / 2));
cv::rectangle(im, pt + cv::Point(0, baseline), pt + cv::Point(text.width, -text.height), CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
cv::putText(im, label, pt, fontface, scale, CV_RGB(0,0,0), thickness, 8);
}

int main()
{
    //cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1); //Create window
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(2); //Capture using any camera connected to your system

while(1){
IplImage * img = cvQueryFrame(capture); 

//show the original image
//cvNamedWindow("Raw");
//cvShowImage("Raw",img);


cv::Mat src(img);

//cv::Mat src = cv::imread("/home/john/Desktop/basic-shapes.png");
//if (src.empty())
//return -1;

// Convert to grayscale
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Use Canny instead of threshold to catch squares with gradient shading
cv::Mat bw;
cv::Canny(gray, bw, 0, 50, 5);

// Find contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
cv::Mat dst = src.clone();

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
// Approximate contour with accuracy proportional
// to the contour perimeter
cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

// Skip small or non-convex objects
if (std::fabs(cv::contourArea(contours[i])) < 1000 || !cv::isContourConvex(approx))
continue;


if (approx.size() >= 4 && approx.size() <= 6)
{
// Number of vertices of polygonal curve
int vtc = approx.size();

// Get the cosines of all corners
std::vector<double> cos;
for (int j = 2; j < vtc+1; j++)
cos.push_back(angle(approx[j%vtc], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));

// Sort ascending the cosine values
std::sort(cos.begin(), cos.end());


// Use the degrees obtained above and the number of vertices
// to determine the shape of the contour
if (vtc == 4)
setLabel(dst, "RECT", contours[i]);
else if (vtc == 5 )
setLabel(dst, "PENTA", contours[i]);
else if (vtc == 6 )
setLabel(dst, "HEXA", contours[i]);
}
else
{
// Detect and label circles
double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
int radius = r.width / 2;

if (std::abs(1 - ((double)r.width / r.height)) <= 0.2 &&
std::abs(1 - (area / (CV_PI * std::pow(radius, 2)))) <= 0.2)
setLabel(dst, "CIR", contours[i]);
}
}

//cv::imshow("src", src);
cv::imshow("dst", dst);
cv::waitKey(10);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You should not mix C and C++ notation, OpenCV has classes for reading in video (Google cv::VideoCapture). 2. The software does not know if an object is moving or not since all it gets is a single frame. You should make sure that you're not having motion blur issues or something like that.